# Undefined relationship (foreign key) in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2005, foreign-key-relationship, undefined-reference

I am working with a SQL Server database which contains almost 850 tables. It has many defined relationships and plenty of undefined relationships(FK), undefined primary keys etc. It is a mess. I don't have access to the application source code, so I can't track down the undefined relations through code.

Is there any software or query by which I can just look at the data and figure out the relationships between the tables? To be more specific, every fields(columns) in each tables are mapped (join) against every columns of all other tables and provide me with a report of some sort. Almost 60% of the cases the column names would be similar in related tables but many tables have same column name for primary key(for example item_id).

I need all those undefined relationships which is making my life miserable everyday!! :(

Comment: Agree with current 2 and (probably) all subsequent replies. It's a "genie" problem: once you let the genie out of the bottle (no declarative referential integrity), it's awfully hard to get it back in the bottle.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to use the profiler to capture the statements being executed and try infer the relationships from that.  This is a tough one, and there aren't any easy solutions that I'm aware of.

Good Luck !

Comment: It is a huge application handled by many groups of developer. I think it will take me an year to just finish clicking all the buttons in the application. I have tried profiler and figured out some of the links, but most of the cases I could not even figure out which application page is associated with a particular database table. Is there anyway I can get all the DML queries executed in the database without writing a trigger to all the tables?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can query the metadata - `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` - filter out things which are highly unlikely to be joined as keys - like TEXT/NVARCHAR(MAX).  Put it in some kind of data dictionary table where you start to tag the columns with information.

You can query with things like:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
    ON C.COLUMN_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME + '_ID';
```

to see if there are obvious matches.

That might help you get a handle on the database.  But it will take a lot of work.

Without a foreign key constraint, it's even possible that they've done things like "multi-keys" where a certain column is a foreign key to one table or another depending on some kind of type selector (these aren't possible with foreign key constraints) - it's possible you won't even see this in the profiler except between separate joins - so one time you might see it join to one table and sometimes another.

Comment: Thank you Cade. I have already tried everything I can with the column name match and figured out the maximum relationships I could. But I want to bring data into picture. For example Table A inner join Table B on a.product_id(int) = b.item_id(varchar(10), the column name are different but the data is smiliar. I would like to join one column against all the columns in 850 tables and do that for all the columns in the database. Is ther any easy way I can do that with a tool of some sort.

Comment: @need_the_buzz You could certainly code generate a comparison of all like data-type fields and get counts on each side and counts of matches.  But no tool I know of.